# can't use key map of perl-support.vim under windows

Tags: vim, perl

perl-support.vim is an awesome plug-in for thoes who use vim to write perl scripts . yes, I've been used it under linux for some thime and it just worked perlfectly for me. But recently I met some problems when trying to use it under windows. among other issue, the biggest headache is that I can't use key
mapping under windows . For example ,`\rs` which suppose to be the key map for syntax check doesn't work.

But use gui button of the perl-support.vim plugin in vim , the syntax updated can be executed.
I have no idea what is the problem , so hope you guys can give me hand .by the way, my vim version is 7.2 .

Answer (score 0):

i get the `\` by pressing `#` at my keyboard under windows7.